# Why does showOpenDialog() open more file choosers?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am trying to create a 'Save to' file chooser. However when i execute the code and hit 'Open' a new filechooser window is opened.  The code:

```
int val = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null);

private void jFileChooser1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    System.out.println(evt.getActionCommand());

    int val = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(val == jFileChooser1.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File filePath = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
         directoryPath = filePath.toString();
         System.out.println("Directory Path: " + directoryPath);
    }else{
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [showSaveDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog%28java.awt.Component%29) method.

Comment: thanks, the code above was actually sitting inside another jFIlechooser resulting in 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int val = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(parent);
```